# Where is the default bash profile file kept?

Tags: bash, command-line, user-profile, .profile

Under Ubuntu 11.10, where is the default bash profile file for new users kept?  I want to edit the default file so that new users get a preconfigured .bash_profile file.

Answer (score 3):

The files located under `/etc/skel` are copied to the user home directory on user creation.

Comment: The default content of /etc/skel is examples.desktop. As far as I know, the bash profile is kept in /etc/profile.

Comment: @zeroseven0183: have you shown the hidden files?